# How to share a dynamic variable between files in PHP(5)?

Tags: php, session, singleton

I have an object of some class that obeys the singleton pattern. I need to initialize it in one file and then use it in others. I don't know how to do this, here is what I tried :

```
//myClass.php
class myClass
{
    private static $instance = null;

    private function __construct($args)
    {
        //stuff
    }

    public function Create($args)
    {
        self::$instance = new myClass($args);
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function Get()
    {
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

//index.php
<?php
require_once('myClass.php');
$instance = myClass::Create($args);
?>
<a href="test.php">Test Me!</a>

//test.php
echo(is_null(myClass::Get())); //displays 1
```

So the problem is that from `test.php`, `myClass::get()` always returns null!

I have also tried to store the instance in the `$_SESSION`, which gives me the same result. Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Forget singleton, you don't need them in PHP. What you're looking for is called session. Why your session does not work I'd say this needs some basic debugging first. http://php.net/session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include file with the class difinition in each file where it used (and it should be included before it will in use).

```
<?php // filename: test.php
include_once("myClass.php");
$oClassInstance = myClass::Get();

var_dump($oClassInstance);
```

BTW

You don't need to define those two methods `Create` and `Get`. You can create only one method called `getInstance`:

```
// only one instance of the class
private static $_oInstance = null;

public static function getInstace()
{
    if (!self::$_oInstance)
    {
        self::$_oInstance = new self();
    }

    return self::$_oInstance;
}
```

And then you can use it like:

```
<?php // filename: index.php
include_once("myClass.php");

// if instance does not exist yet then it will be created and returned
$oClass = myClass::getInstace();

<?php // filename: test.php
include_once("myClass.php");

// the instance already created and stored in myClass::$_oInstance variable
// so it just will be returned
$oClass = myClass::getInstance();
```

**UPD**

If you have to put some arguments into constructor just use predefined arguments:

```
private function __construct($aArg)
{
    // this code will be launched once when instance is created
    // in the any other cases you'll return already created object
}

public static function getInstance($aArgs = null)
{
    if (!self::$_oInstance)
    {
        self::$_oInstance = new self($aArgs);
    }

    return self::$_oInstance;
}
```

**ANSWER**

Sorry that you have to scroll a few screens to find this =)))
The reason why you can't use `myClass::Get()` in you context is that you have 2 scripts that means - two different programs.
Singleton should be used within a single application (one script).

So in your case, correct usage will be module system:
 - index.php
 - main.php
 - test.php

```
// file: index.php
include_once "myClass.php"

$module = $_GET["module"];
include_once $module ".php";

// file: main.php
$oClass = myClass::Create($someArgs);
var_dump($oClass); // you'll see you class body

// file: test.php
$oClass=  myClass::Get();
var_dump($oClass); // you'll see the same class body as above
```

And your links will be:

- index.php?module=**main**
- index.php?module=**test**

Comment: I forgot to put the include in test.php but it is indeed present in my actual test code, so the problem doesn't come from here. Also, I do need the create function because I need to pass arguments to the private constructor on first invocation!

Comment: I updated my answer and added *ANSWER* section =) Please check it out, hope this helps you ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Create() function need to check whether $instance property already has a value before creating a new object. For example

```
public function Create()
{
    if (is_null(self::$instance)) {
        self::$instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

In test.php you can just call myClass::Create(), no need to have the Get() function at all